# Should I use an unsigned char instead of an int to store values that will never be greater than 255?

Tags: c++, char, int

In a C++ program I am writing for fun there are frequently numeric values being used that will absolutely never be greater than 255, and I am therefore storing them as unsigned chars to save on memory used (as an unsigned char only uses a byte, as opposed to the 4 bytes of an int). Is this a good idea? Are there any downsides to doing this?

I appreciate tips and insight anyone can give.

Comment: "Are there any downsides to doing this?" yes you may save very little if any but program can work significantly slower.

Comment: This is totally an opinion based question. But you will lose the benefits of strict aliasing for doing this, which may damage your execution speed. Aside from that `char`s will behave very differently in input/output settings. If the memory savings are still worth all that to you, I'd go with an `uint8_t` over an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a trade-off.

Given that you are using `unsigned char` to represent non-negative (presumably) values that don't exceed `255`, you will save on memory usage for storing the particular values.

If your code does arithmetic operations on those `unsigned char`, then the values may be implicitly promoted to `int`, the operation done using `int`s, and then the result converted back.    This is consistent with the fact that quite a few real-world machines do not have machine registers that work directly with `char` types, but do have registers and instructions that are optimised for a larger "native" integral type i.e. `int`.  Such to-and-fro conversions can mean that code which does a sequence of operations on `unsigned char`s can have measurably lower speed than coding to use variables of type `int`.      (Notionally, an implementation might "optimise out" such to-and-fro conversions, if analysis shows there is no change of observable result from a sequence of operations, but it is not required to)

Generally speaking, for representing numeric values, I would suggest not using `unsigned char` and to default to using `int` (or another suitable integral type if the range of values you need to represent goes beyond the range that an `int` is guaranteed able to represent).   Get the code working first and, if you decide to optimise your code to save on memory, do testing/profiling on representative target systems to determine the extent of any performance impact of using `unsigned char`.   If using C++11 or later, you might also consider using `uint8_t` (on implementations that support it) but bear in mind there may be similar trade-offs with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any downside but you might not use lesser memory depending on the order of your member variable definitions because of padding bytes(this only applies to classes).

Comment: No it applies not only to classes, when you declare scope variables they also padded.